Spring boot starter does not recognized pem files
I updated spring boot package(spring-boot-starter-parent to version 2.7.18 and enabled SSL.
I tried to run my app on Windows server and on Ubuntu 23.04 machine.
When I'm uploading the server on windows I'm getting this error:
The PKCS#8 encryption algorithm with DER encoded OID of [2a864886f70d010503] was not recognised
or this error:
caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
When I tried to upload the app on Ubuntu 23.04 the app initialized correctly.
EDIT
The PEM file was created by using this openssl commands:

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout <key_name>.pem -out <cert_name>.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey <key_name>.pem -in <cert_name>.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in keyStore.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out <cert_name>.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in keyStore.p12 -clcerts -out <key_name>.key

EDIT2
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:594)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
    at com.Main.main(Main.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1332)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1418)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1039)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:282)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:112)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:268)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Where and how (and when) was this PEM (key) file created? What Java ('vendor' and version) is running on Windows, and does it have any modified provider configuration? That OID is 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 aka pbeWithMD5AndDES-CBC from PKCS5v1 and has been implemented by the SunJCE provider in every Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK Java since 6 at least, but is not at all secure (since last century) and should not be used or ever have been used in any context where security is or was desired.

@dave_thompson_085 I created the PEM file in my Ubuntu 23.04 machine. On Windows and Ubuntu I'm working with AWS Corretto 17. I updated the original question and with the process of create the PEM file.

(1) I assume you used the output of step 4. Aside: going via pkcs12 here is convoluted and a waste of time; step 3 accomplishes nothing and step 4 either does no more than 'cat' or at most a trivial reencryption that can be done more easily without pkcs12. But anyway: I don't have real Ubuntu 23.04 but from dockerhub it has OpenSSL 3.0.8, and (as expected) your commands produce a key encrypted with PBES2/HmacSHA256/DES-EDE3-CBC (i.e. 3DES/TripleDES) not any PKCS5v1 scheme. Try awk '/BEGIN ENC/,/END ENC/' keyfile | openssl asn1parse to check.

(2) OTOH it's not hard to explicitly create a encrypted key with that obsolete and bad scheme. I don't use actual AWS, but downloading the Windows and Debian (Ubuntu) versions from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/downloads-list.html (currently 17.0.11+9) to my system both show PBEwithMD5andDES as implemented (as expected) and the obvious code using javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKey + SecretKeyFactory + Cipher decrypts okay (as expected). Do you have a complete stacktrace, or can you get one e.g. with a debugger? Some idea of what the code is doing would help.

@dave_thompson_085 I added the full stacktrace.

Okay, it's in tomcat-embed-core which according to Maven is 9.0.83 for your springboot, and it appears that changed around then from simple code like I described (getAlgName with a tweak+SKF+Cipher) (which does work for PBES1) to code that can handle more PBES2 than Java does -- but no longer handles PBES1 at all. That explains a change. It still doesn't explain how you got OpenSSL to create PBES1-MD5-singleDES which I can't do anywhere. ...

... Can you newly generate a (throwaway) key and look at it with asn1parse, as I suggested above, and compare to structure/metadata on your real key?

@dave_thompson_085 the original key returns Error: offset out of range. The new key I generated returns a correct answer. For an unknown reason when I added the key with the built-in keytool the server uploaded correctly.

If the original key can be parsed by Tomcat I can't understand the asn1parse method failing on it. At this point I don't think I can help further without looking at the key but I can't recommend you publish it (even encrypted).

@dave_thompson_085 I'm really aprraciate your kind help!
